# How to write a generic UIRectCorner function?

Tags: objective-c

Here is the objective-c code:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_backgroundImageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];
```

What I would like to do is, I would like to parse 4 booleans, and modify the `byRoundingCorners`. But the problem is that, for example, I have `isRectCornerBottomLeft` is `YES`, and rest of them is `NO`, I will do something like this:

`maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_backgroundImageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];`

But how can I control the `UIRectCorner`? of course, I can do many if else to check whether the `isRectCornerBottomLeft` is `YES`, and which one is `NO` to write every conditions out. But apart from that, how can I simplify that logic? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

There is no real way to "simplify" the logic. If you have 4 `BOOL` values, you need to check each one:

```
UIRectCorner corners = 0;
if (isRectCornerBottomLeft) {
    corners |= UIRectCornerBottomLeft;
}
if (isRectCornerBottomRight) {
    corners |= UIRectCornerBottomRight;
}
if (isRectCornerTopLeft) {
    corners |= UIRectCornerTopLeft;
}
if (isRectCornerTopRight) {
    corners |= UIRectCornerTopRight;
}
```

You could also do something like:

```
UIRectCorner corners = (isRectCornerBottomLeft ? UIRectCornerBottomLeft : 0) |
                       (isRectCornerBottomRight ? UIRectCornerBottomRight : 0) |
                       (isRectCornerTopLeft ? UIRectCornerTopLeft : 0) |
                       (isRectCornerTopRight ? UIRectCornerTopRight : 0);
```

Comment: What is this operator...`|=` I first time seeing this.

Comment: It's the "or equals" operator. `x |= y` is the same as doing `x = x | y`. Just like the `+=` and `*=` operators. These are all from C.