# Round Specific Corners - SKShapeNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have a SKShapeNode which needs to have each one of it's corners rounded if a specific condition is met. Reading the answer provided from the link below, this seemed quiet easy, as I would simply use |= to rounded addition corners that required rounding (4x if statements).

[How to write a generic UIRectCorner function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296222/how-to-write-a-generic-uirectcorner-function)

However, this is not working! When I use the below code, I get the error message "Binart operator '|=' cannot be applied to two 'UIRectCorner' operands"

```
var corners: UIRectCorner = UIRectCorner(rawValue: 0) | UIRectCorner(rawValue: 1)
```

or

```
var corners: UIRectCorner = UIRectCorner(rawValue: 0)
corners |= UIRectCorner(rawValue: 1)
```

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a very handy extension that I use heavily in all of my SpriteKit games.  It takes the existing SKShapeNode and copies all of its relevant properties then removes and makes a new one with whichever corners you specify to be rounded.  Note: you should not use this if the shape node has any children as they will not persist through the new creation.  So always use this method before adding any children to it.

```
shapeNode.roundCorners(topLeft:true,topRight: true,bottomLeft:false,bottomRight:false,radius:20,parent:self)


extension SKShapeNode {
    func roundCorners(topLeft:Bool,topRight:Bool,bottomLeft:Bool,bottomRight:Bool,radius: CGFloat,parent: SKNode){
        let newNode = SKShapeNode(rect: self.frame)
        newNode.fillColor = self.fillColor
        newNode.lineWidth = self.lineWidth
        newNode.position = self.position
        newNode.name = self.name
        newNode.fillColor = self.fillColor
        newNode.strokeColor = self.strokeColor
        newNode.fillTexture = self.fillTexture
        self.removeFromParent()
        parent.addChild(newNode)
        var corners = UIRectCorner()
        if topLeft { corners = corners.union(.bottomLeft) }
        if topRight { corners = corners.union(.bottomRight) }
        if bottomLeft { corners = corners.union(.topLeft) }
        if bottomRight { corners = corners.union(.topRight) }
        newNode.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -(newNode.frame.width / 2),y:-(newNode.frame.height / 2),width: newNode.frame.width, height: newNode.frame.height),byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width:radius,height:radius)).cgPath
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This looks great! But I'm getting an error, 'Expected expression in container literal' at the 'if topLeft' line. Do you know why I'd be getting this error?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo on the line before.  It should end with `UIRectCorner()` not `UIRectCorner([`.  I fixed it

Comment: Please consider up voting or marking as the answer if you feel this has helped or solved your question. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of solved my problem. The |= and += wasn't working, but =[previousValue, newValue] seems to work. My code below. If there is a better way, please let me know.

```
func roundCorners() {

    let TR = true
    let TL = true
    let BR = false
    let BL = true

    var corners: UIRectCorner = []

    if TR == true {
        corners = [corners, .topRight]
    }

    if TL == true {
        corners = [corners, .topLeft]
    }

    if BR == true {
        corners = [corners, .bottomRight]
    }

    if BL == true {
        corners = [corners, .bottomLeft]
    }

    let rect = CGRect(x: -50, y: -50, width: 100, height: 100)
    let cornerSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)

    let shape = SKShapeNode()
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.black
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: cornerSize).cgPath
    addChild(shape)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5.2.x:

```
extension SKShapeNode {
    convenience init(corners:UIRectCorner, size:CGSize, radius:CGFloat) {
        // flips corners vertically for UIBezierPath and SKSpriteKit
        var flipCorners = UIRectCorner()
        flipCorners = corners.contains(.topLeft) ? flipCorners.union(.bottomLeft): flipCorners
        flipCorners = corners.contains(.topRight) ? flipCorners.union(.bottomRight): flipCorners
        flipCorners = corners.contains(.bottomLeft) ? flipCorners.union(.topLeft): flipCorners
        flipCorners = corners.contains(.bottomRight) ? flipCorners.union(.topRight): flipCorners
        self.init(path: UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: CGRect(origin:CGPoint.zero,size:size), byRoundingCorners: flipCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)).cgPath)
    }
}
```

---

### Usage:

```
let roundedShape = SKShapeNode(corners: UIRectCorner([.topLeft,.topRight]), size: CGSize(width:200,height:100), radius: 16)
```